# EventAggregator HelloWorld Prism

Tags: prism

Looking for a simple helloWorld EventAggregator example. I am trying to understand this and having a little tough time following the RI example.
Thanks
N

Answer (score 3):

Prism 4.0 includes EventAggregation QuickStart example - it is simpler than RI. See [Prism 4 Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921173%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx) for fore details or check the sources at \Quickstarts\EventAggregation

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand the `EventAggregator` example you must follow the initial example of [HelloWorldDesktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921141%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx) as well, so that yu can get an idea of the updation in this example.
There are also number of samples available, if you want to get an idea of `EventAggregator`, you can choose another simple example as well.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355473/Prism-EventAggregator-Sample